# Psycopg2 Operational Error SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

We are using python for communication to postgres sqlalchemy database and time to time there occurs error

```
    ERROR 2017-05-24 16:45:55,072 45610 (psycopg2.OperationalError) SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
 [SQL: '\n        SELECT sys.check_permissions(%(username)s, ARRAY[%(permission_0)s]);\n    '] [parameters: {'username': 'miksanikm', 'permission_0': 'searchBrokerContact'}]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/python/projects/allrisk_isac/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyne/application.py", line 122, in process_request
    self.event_manager.fire_event('method_call', ctx)
  File "/home/python/projects/allrisk_isac/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyne/_base.py", line 442, in fire_event
    handler(ctx)
  File "wsgi.py", line 161, in _on_method_call
    if not ctx.udc.hasPermissions(ctx.udc.method_name):
  File "wsgi.py", line 145, in hasPermissions
    return system_lib.checkPermission(self.username, *args)
  File "./app/system/lib.py", line 126, in checkPermission
    ''' % permissions), args)
  File "/home/python/projects/allrisk_isac/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 945, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/python/projects/allrisk_isac/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 263, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/python/projects/allrisk_isac/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1053, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/home/python/projects/allrisk_isac/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1189, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/python/projects/allrisk_isac/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1393, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/home/python/projects/allrisk_isac/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/home/python/projects/allrisk_isac/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/python/projects/allrisk_isac/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 470, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
```

so after this call whole app fails. So it is quite severe error, but I think it's in postgres itself. Do you have any ideas, why is this happening?

EDIT:

Python query code
PS: If you have tips to edit it to be more readible, tell me

```
def searchBrokerContact(rcic, name, surname, city, phone, email, id_person_company, id_broker):
    def regExPercent(x):
        if x is None:
            return '%'
        return '%'+x+'%'
    connection = connections['default']
    if len(rcic) > 0:
        condition = u' (pc.ico = :rcic OR pc.rc = :rcic) LIMIT 50'
    else:
        condition = u''' ((lower(pc.name) like lower(:name) or (pc.name IS NULL AND :name IN ('%%', '%')))
        AND (lower(pc.surname) like lower(:surname) OR lower(pc.company_name) like lower(:surname))
        AND (lower(ad.city) like lower(:city) OR (ad.city IS NULL AND :city IN ('%%', '%')))
        AND (regexp_replace(pc.phone_mobile, '[ +]*', '', 'g') like regexp_replace(:phone, '[ +]*', '', 'g') OR (pc.phone_mobile IS NULL AND :phone IN ('%%', '%')))
        AND (pc.email like :email OR (pc.email IS NULL AND :email IN ('%%', '%') )) ) LIMIT 50'''
    query = connection.execute(text(
    u"""
    SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN pc.organization_type = 10 THEN pc.rc ELSE pc.ico END AS client_icorc,
    CASE
      WHEN pc.organization_type IN (10, 20) THEN
        btrim((((COALESCE(pc.degree, ''::character varying)::text || ' '::text) || COALESCE(pc.name, ''::character varying)::text) || ' '::text) || COALESCE(pc.surname, ''::character varying)::text)
      ELSE
        pc.company_name
    END AS client_name,
    pc.organization_type,
    pc.id_person_company AS id_person_company,
    pc.email AS email,
    pc.phone_mobile AS phone,
    btrim((((((COALESCE(ad.street, ''::character varying)::text || ' '::text) || COALESCE(ad.land_registry_num, ad.house_num, ''::character varying)::text) || ', '::text) || COALESCE(ad.zip, ''::character varying)::text) || ' '::text) || COALESCE(ad.city, ''::character varying)::text) AS address_client,
    CASE
      WHEN ad.id_address = ac.id_address THEN
        CASE WHEN pc.organization_type = 10
        THEN 'shodná s adresou trvalého pobytu'
            ELSE 'shodná s adresou sídla'
        END
      ELSE
        btrim((((((COALESCE(ac.street, ''::character varying)::text || ' '::text) || COALESCE(ac.land_registry_num, ac.house_num, ''::character varying)::text) || ', '::text) || COALESCE(ac.zip, ''::character varying)::text) || ' '::text) || COALESCE(ac.city, ''::character varying)::text)
    END AS address_c,
    pc.degree,
    pc.sex,
    pc.name,
    pc.surname,
    pc.organization_type,
    pc.rc,
    pc.ico,
    pc.bank_account,
    pc.bank_code,
    pc.bank_prefix,
    ad.street,
    ad.house_num,
    ad.land_registry_num,
    ad.city,
    ad.zip,
    ad.id_country,
    ac.street AS street_c,
    ac.house_num AS house_num_c,
    ac.land_registry_num AS land_registry_num_c,
    ac.city AS city_c,
    ac.zip AS zip_c,
    CASE WHEN ac.id_address = ad.id_address THEN false ELSE true END AS has_cor,
    pc.identity_card,
    pc.company_name,
    id.card_from,
    id.card_to,
    id.card_num,
    id.card_authority,
    id.card_type,
    CASE WHEN id.id_identity NOTNULL THEN true ELSE false END AS has_identity,
    bc.created::date
    FROM
        personal.person_company AS pc
        INNER JOIN personal.broker_contact AS bc ON bc.id_person_company = pc.id_person_company
        INNER JOIN personal.address AS ad ON ad.id_address = pc.id_address
        LEFT JOIN personal.address AS ac ON ac.id_address = pc.id_address_mailing
        LEFT JOIN personal.identity AS id ON id.id_identity = pc.id_identity
        LEFT JOIN personal.client AS cl ON cl.id_person_company = pc.id_person_company
    WHERE bc.deleted IS NULL and pc.deleted IS Null AND cl.id_client Is NULL
        AND bc.id_broker = :id_broker
        AND
    """+condition), id_person_company=id_person_company, rcic=rcic, name=regExPercent(name), surname=regExPercent(surname), city=regExPercent(city), phone=regExPercent(phone), email=regExPercent(email), id_broker=id_broker)
    output = []
    for row in query:
        item = ClientListItem(id_person_company=row['id_person_company'],
                              client_name=row['client_name'],
                              client_icorc=row['client_icorc'],
                              address=row['address_client'],
                              address_cor=row['address_c'],
                              phone=row['phone'],
                              email=row['email'],
                              city=row['city'],
                              created=row['created'])
        output.append(item)
    return output
```

It is in restAPI for java here is service.py code

```
@rpc(ByteArray(default=['']), ByteArray(default=['']), ByteArray(default=['']), ByteArray(default=['']), ByteArray(default=['']), ByteArray(default=['']), Integer(default=None), Integer(default=None), _returns=ClientList)
    def searchBrokerContact(ctx, rcic, name, surname, city, phone, email, id_person_company, id_broker):
        '''
        Service returns list of contacts
        '''
        list= external_contract_lib.searchBrokerContact(rcic[0], name[0], surname[0], city[0], phone[0], email[0], id_person_company, id_broker)
        return ClientList(list=list)
```

Comment: share your executed query pls?

Comment: there are newline characters in your query

Comment: also: provide code sample where you are generating and executing query

Comment: Added codes to question